# Provisioning profile error while installing custom enterprise app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have developed an iPhone enterprise app for a client.

The application is working properly on all devices, however, on one user's device, the application installation gives an error
`Unable to download application. <Application name> could not be installed`.

This error message comes up while the application icon shows the installation progress.

On further investigation, we found that the enterprise distribution profile is not being installed and the following logs are seen in the console.

> Mar 19 12:44:27 unknown SpringBoard[15] : could not save
>   thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null)
>   path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache
>   com.mobility.plocator-21526CEE-3E35-4259-B04B-1EC051349CAB'
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] : could not save
>   thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null)
>   path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.mobility.plocator-060A1EE8-077D-49E7-A4B4-5A12BCEB09C3'
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : unable to create
>   directory for provisioning profiles: Permission denied
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000
>   install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 49165
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000
>   verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620395
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000
>   preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at
>   /var/tmp/install_staging.H0131I/foo_extracted/Payload/PFinder.app
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000
>   install_application: Could not preflight application install
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000
>   handle_install: API failed
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000 send_message:
>   failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
>
> Mar 19 12:44:28 unknown installd[525] : 2ff7f000 send_error:
>   Could not send error response to client

Comment: Is the device UDID included to the profile (i mean that you did check it to be sure)?

Comment: It is a generic distribution profile for the enterprise. I don't think the each individual device has to be added to the profile.

Comment: @user1281732Can you please suggest me for the best way that how to deploy an app using Enterprise program (299$) without adding device's UDID? I have searched alot but haven't got any good answer..thanks

Answer (score 0):

There can be few solutions:

1. You can revoke current distribution certificate and create new certificate and try with that. Sometimes certificate may also have issues.
2. Check your App ID it should be in format '**com.companyname.appname**'.
3. Check keychain for multiple certificate installed with same name. You should remove any other certificate with same name.